# Query Shows multiple listings of same info

Tags: sql

I'm using this query to find all the machines on the network (using dell kace) that have an expired warranty according to their service tag.

However, when I run the query, some of the machines are listed twice but should only be listed once.

Here is an example of the output where machine example3 is correctly listed but example1 is listed twice.

```
#      Machine Name     Service Tag

1       example1           abcd123

2       example1           abcd123

3       example3            abcd124
```

Code:

```
SELECT     

M.NAME AS MACHINE_NAME, M.CS_MODEL AS MODEL, DA.SERVICE_TAG,
DA.SHIP_DATE,M.USER_LOGGED AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_USER, DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE,
DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION, DW.END_DATE AS EXPIRATION_DATE

FROM

DELL_WARRANTY DW

JOIN

DELL_ASSET DA ON (DW.SERVICE_TAG = DA.SERVICE_TAG)

JOIN

MACHINE M

ON (M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.PARENT_SERVICE_TAG OR M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.SERVICE_TAG)

LEFT JOIN

DELL_WARRANTY DW2 ON DW2.SERVICE_TAG=DW.SERVICE_TAG and DW2.END_DATE > NOW()

WHERE

M.CS_MANUFACTURER LIKE '%dell%'

AND

M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER!=''

AND

 DA.DISABLED != 1

AND

DW.END_DATE < NOW()

AND

DW2.SERVICE_TAG IS NULL;
```

Any ideas on how to make computers with the same machine name and service tags only output once?  Thanks.

Comment: Easy way is to use `SELECT DISTINCT`. Better way is to understand why some records are selected twice. Probably, some table that is joined has several records for some of machines.

Comment: yeah I've tried using Distinct as well as DistinctRow and it still doesn't seem to help

Comment: you need to find what data is DIFFERENT on the 'repeated' rows - then see why those are in the result set.

Answer (score 1):

Let me make the assumption that you have a reasonable data model and reasonably populated data.  That means that the duplicates are not coming from inappropriate data stored in the database.

Your query (formatted so I can read it) is:

```
SELECT M.NAME AS MACHINE_NAME, M.CS_MODEL AS MODEL, DA.SERVICE_TAG,
       DA.SHIP_DATE, M.USER_LOGGED AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_USER, DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE,
       DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION, DW.END_DATE AS EXPIRATION_DATE
FROM DELL_WARRANTY DW JOIN
     DELL_ASSET DA
     ON DW.SERVICE_TAG = DA.SERVICE_TAG JOIN
     MACHINE M
     ON M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.PARENT_SERVICE_TAG OR
        M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.SERVICE_TAG LEFT JOIN
     DELL_WARRANTY DW2
     ON DW2.SERVICE_TAG = DW.SERVICE_TAG and DW2.END_DATE > NOW()
WHERE M.CS_MANUFACTURER LIKE '%dell%' AND
      M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER <> '' AND
      DA.DISABLED <> 1;
```

The suspect `join` is the one on `Machine` because it has an `or`.  So, two machines might match different parts of the service tag, resulting in multiple very similar rows.

If your concern is specifically about machine names and service tags (the two columns you highlighted in the question), then you can fix those duplicates by ending the query with:

```
group by M.NAME, DA.SERVICE_TAG
```

(This assumes that you are using MySQL -- based on the syntax of your query.  Most other databases would require aggregation functions around the rest of the columns in `select`.)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting a DISTINCT infront of M.Name

OR playing with the joins like

```
 SELECT     

M.NAME AS MACHINE_NAME, M.CS_MODEL AS MODEL, DA.SERVICE_TAG,
DA.SHIP_DATE,M.USER_LOGGED AS LAST_LOGGED_IN_USER, DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_CODE,
DW.SERVICE_LEVEL_DESCRIPTION, DW.END_DATE AS EXPIRATION_DATE

FROM

DELL_WARRANTY DW

INNER JOIN

DELL_ASSET DA ON (DW.SERVICE_TAG = DA.SERVICE_TAG)

INNER JOIN

 MACHINE M

ON (M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.PARENT_SERVICE_TAG OR M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER = DA.SERVICE_TAG)

INNER JOIN

DELL_WARRANTY DW2 ON DW2.SERVICE_TAG=DW.SERVICE_TAG and DW2.END_DATE > NOW()

 WHERE

M.CS_MANUFACTURER LIKE '%dell%'

AND

M.BIOS_SERIAL_NUMBER!=''

AND

DA.DISABLED != 1

AND

DW.END_DATE < NOW()

AND

DW2.SERVICE_TAG IS NULL;
```

Comment: Using DISTINCT didn't fix anything and using your second idea returns nothing.